# I want to update a GridView based off of a value selected from a DropDownList by editing my SqlDataSource

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, data-binding, sqldatasource

I'm trying to accomplish this by updating the SelectCommand on my SqlDataSource, clearing the GridView, and then reapplying the GridView.DataBind() based off the value in the dropdown. It's not working, and honestly, I'm totally new to this, so I very well could just be doing things incorrectly. Here's some sample code that gives an idea of what I've got:

```
Protected Sub drp_product_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles drp_product.SelectedIndexChanged

    grd_ingredientview.DataSource = Nothing
    grd_ingredientview.DataBind()
    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "blah blah sample select command" + drp_product.SelectedValue
    grd_ingredientview.DataSource = SqlDataSource1
    grd_ingredientview.DataBind()

End Sub
```

Again, this doesn't work, and throws up an error, saying: `Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'grd_ingredientview'. Remove one definition.`

Any help with this would be appreciated, along with a description for why this isn't working and how your suggestion does. Still learning a lot of this. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a `DataSourceID` defined on your GridView? Could you post the markup?

Comment: @DaveB I did most of this through the Design view, so a lot of it is auto generated. Is this what you're looking for? In my actual aspx page, I have the gridview defined with this:
`<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1"`

Comment: @DaveB Sorry! Posted the wrong snippet. It's this instead:
`<asp:GridView DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"`

Answer (score 1):

Well, use code to load up the grid view in the first place, and you can dump the the datasoruce1. (just remove it from the web form). (but ANSWER NO to re-create the fields an update the grid view if prompted).

So yes, use the wizard, let it create that data source. Choose your columns. Test the grid. Ok, now it works. Now that the grid been built?

then delete the Datasourc1 from the page. And then for the property sheet, remove the datasource setting. This one:

[image]

So, now we removed that Datasource1 object from the page, and  the setting that points to that datasource.

And do the SAME idea with the combo box. Use the wizard, even let it build + add a data source for the combo box. And again, delete the data source and again remove the datasource setting for the combo box just like we did for the gird.

So, now we can (and will) freely use code to fill out the data grid.

So, on page load, the one time (first time) data load, we can do this:

```
    If IsPostBack = False Then
        ' first time page load - display the grid.
        Call LoadGrid("")
        Call LoadCombobox
    End If
```

And note, for the combo box? Again, you can freely use the wizards to setup the combo box, but AGAIN remove that data source setting like we did for the grid.

So, now all our code looks like this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If IsPostBack = False Then
        ' first time page load - display the grid.
        Call LoadGrid("")
        Call LoadCombobox
    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadGrid(Optional strWhere As String = "")

    Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT * from tblHotels "
    If strWhere <> "" Then
        strSQL += " WHERE " & strWhere
    End If

    Me.GridView1.DataSource = Myrst(strSQL)
    Me.GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub

Sub LoadComboBox()
    Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT City from tblHotels GROUP BY City"

    Me.DropDownList1.DataSource = Myrst(strSQL)
    Me.DropDownList1.DataBind()

End Sub

Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim strWhere As String
    strWhere = "City = '" & DropDownList1.SelectedValue & "'"
    Call LoadGrid(strWhere)

End Sub
```

Now the only part I left out was MyRst(). It simply returns a datatable. So, you can use that code (and place it outside in a standard code module.

That way you can use it over and over though out your application, and not have to create a connect object and sql command over and over until you go nuts.

It also means you only EVER use/get/grab a connection string in ONE place in your code, so it is easy to change it when you change the database.

So the handy dandy routine that saves you having over and over to re-write query code and the connection object is this:

```
Public Function Myrst(strSQL As String, Optional strCon As String = "") As DataTable

    ' this also allows one to pass custom connection string - 
    ' if not passed, then default

    If strCon = "" Then
        strCon = My.Settings.TestDatabase3
    End If

    Using mycon As New SqlConnection(strCon)

      Dim oReader As New SqlDataAdapter
      Dim rstData As New DataSet

      oReader.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(strSQL, mycon)

      Try
        oReader.Fill(rstData)
        Return rstData.Tables(0)
      Catch
        Return Nothing
      End Try
  End Using

End Function
```

So, with the above simple helper routine, then the code is very easy to write. In fact I find its less code then even desktop code or even writing code in MS-Access.

so the above simple example would select a city from the combo box, and then filter/set the gride to only display that city.
And if you want, you don't have to fill the grid on page load, since the user is about to select a combo box value. So, just comment out the LoadGrid on page load, and only call it when you make a combo (dropdownlist) selection.

As noted, don't forget to set the dropdown list auto-post back = true.

All in all? The above is not a lot of code, and is no more then say doing this for the desktop, or even doing this in Access.

Comment: Connection not disposed?

Comment: Well, the often suggested approach is to wrap the connection in using. However,  USING is really critical if for un-managed code calls (say using Ghostscript.net which in turn uses a un-managed library. For managed? Well, the garbage collector will free this stuff up - but I do accept it better to force the issue. I done an edit wrapped the con in a using. note that returns inside of a using are valid and don't effect that using will add a dispose on exit.

Comment: Thanks! i appreciate it a ton! By reading through your explanation of things however, I realized _why_ I was trying to use the built in DataSourceID in the first place, and that's because it offers a really easy "Edit" mode option built into the Design view. One of the fields in my grid will need to be editable, and will update the server once accepted. I hate to be more of a bother, but any suggestions on that?